# NHibernate 3.0 and LINQ: what am I missing?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I recently decided to upgrade my web application from NHibernate 2.1 to 3.0, the latest version of NH. I also decided to upgrade from .NET 2.0 to 3.5 for best compatibility with Mono (the webapp runs only in Linux) now that it's mature enough.

I wanted to play a bit with LINQ and NHibernate, since I also saw that the NHibernate.Linq namespace is included in the release.

However, when I try to write a LINQ using the `ISession` instance, I don't get the `Linq<T>` method.

I read i many *old* blog posts that in order to use LINQ to NH you must use the NHContrib package.

## My question is

Do I still need to download NHContrib? Version 3.0 of NH is much more recent than NHContrib's LINQ to NH, and I saw the Linq namespace included in the release

## Or,

is it due to the Visual Studio 2010 upgrade with 2.0->3.5 framework upgrade? I double-checked and target framework IS 3.5.

Unfortunately, I can't find comprehensive documentation on NH 3.0 except the full class documentation, which is more useful for NH developers than general-purpose development

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NHibernate 3.0 has it's own LINQ providerb built in, you can access it via .Query<T>

So you don't need Ayende's NHibernate.Linq provider anymore.

Also, the NHibernate 3.0 Cookbook may help you out.

https://www.packtpub.com/nhibernate-3-0-cookbook/book

Answer (score 0):

Also be aware that the inbuilt LINQ provider doesn't supprort the `.Equals` method in `Where` clauses, you need to use `==` instead.  For instance, where the following used to work with NHibernate.Linq in 2x:

```
(from e in myEntities where e.Name.Equals(nameLookup) select e)
```

You now need to do

```
(from e in myEntities where e.Name == nameLookup select e)
```

Comment: Can you explain better? I need to perform a value-compare between objects: your example probably shows a string which can be compared with ==, but my objects have Equals() method overloaded to perform primary-key comparison. Should I explicitly compare the primary key rather than the full object? Example (from e in employees where e.Boss.Equals(me) select e), where Boss is type Person, what should I do with that?

Comment: We do too, and we just use the `==` operator, ie: `where e.Boss == me select e`

Comment: (All our stuff used to be `.Equals` as part of the migration to 3.0 we had to update the queries to `==` and they all still work as before)

Comment: Hmm - says fixed in 3.0.0GA - thats what I downloaded.  Strange.